# How do I make all selected lights in the scene share the same power value while negating color data

Tags: light

I have around a hundred point lights in this city scene that have variation in both light power and color. I noticed that, far into the project, the building interior room lights are not as bright as anticipated. I only want to change the light power value in the selected lights by linking object data from one light to the other lights, but that also changes the light color which is not what I wanted. How can I make the light power data the same on all selected lights without affecting color value?
[image]

[image]

Comment: just because i am curious: how many weeks takes this to render just one frame?

Comment: why not emission nodes instead of lights?

Answer (score 6):

Select all your lights, go into the *Object Data* panel, choose the *Power* value you want and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, or select all your lights, select the one with the right *Power* value at the end, right click on the value and *Copy To Selected*.